# set loader when changing page on angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to set a loader when starting changing page and remove it ONLY when the entire page is TOTALY rendered to avoid clipping bugs.

I already set the loader, see below :

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(scope, next, current) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('START_ROUTE_CHANGE');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: The code you illustrated looks for changes to the route, are you talking about actually moving off to another page?

Comment: yes because when you're changing page the chaning is quite violent.. i want to get a smooth rendering thanks to the loader

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `$routeChangeStart` for showing the loader and `$routeChangeError`, `$routeChangeSuccess` for hiding it.

You can avoid the ugly effect from showing images which are still not fully loaded by prefetching them from the partial and use resolve for resolving the dependencies for the given page.

Comment: Yes i just tried this method, it's working well but i got another question about this. is it possible from the resolve callback to broadcast an event to any controller ?

Comment: Use `$rootScope.$emit('event_name', params);`.